# Count and sort an array of objects of nested arrays by highest number of duplicates

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, multidimensional-array, javascript-objects

This might sound like it has already been answered, but I have tried a lot of solutions on StackOverflow. None solves my problem. I have a complex array of nested arras and data sets which contains more nested sub-sets or lists. I want to merge them down and/or find a way to count and sort duplicates by certain key. Here is the real data I have:
**EDIT**

```
      var arr =[  
   {  
      "Brand 1":[  
         {  
            "NAME":"SHIRT",
            "SIZE":"M"
         },
         {  
            "NAME":"PANTS",
            "SIZE":"L"
         }
      ],
      "Brand 2":[  
         {  
            "NAME":"JEANS",
            "SIZE":"S"
         },
         {  
            "NAME":"TROUSER",
            "SIZE":"S"
         },
         {  
            "NAME":"TROUSERS",
            "SIZE":"L"
         }
      ],
      "Brand 3":[  
         {  
            "SIZE":"L",
            "NAME":"JEANS"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "Brand x":[  
         {  
            "NAME":"SNEAKERS",
            "SIZE":"M"
         }
      ],
      "Brand 2":[  
         {  
            "NAME":"BLAZER",
            "SIZE":"L"
         },
         {  
            "NAME":"FUR COAT",
            "SIZE":"L"
         }
      ],
      "Brand 1":[  
         {  
            "SIZE":"XL",

            "NAME":"BLAZER"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

The number of sub-sets is not fixed. As you can see, this is a complex array and solutions out there don't go deeper than 2 levels or 1 dimension. Desired Output: 
**EDIT**

```
      var arr =  [  
   {  
      "Brand 1":[  
         {  
            "NAME":"SHIRT",
            "SIZE":"M"
         },
         {  
            "NAME":"PANTS",
            "SIZE":"L"
         },
         {  
            "COUNT":"3"
         }
      ],
      "Brand 2":[  
         {  
            "NAME":"JEANS",
            "SIZE":"S"
         },
         {  
            "NAME":"TROUSER",
            "SIZE":"S"
         },
         {  
            "NAME":"TROUSERS",
            "SIZE":"L"
         },
         {  
            "COUNT":"5"
         }
      ],
      "Brand 3":[  
         {  
            "SIZE":"L",
            "NAME":"JEANS"
         },
         {  
            "COUNT":"3"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "Brand x":[  
         {  
            "NAME":"SNEAKERS",
            "SIZE":"M"
         },
         {  
            "COUNT":"1"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Can you see the "COUNT" variable at the end of each brand array? That's what I want and sort the items according to it.

I have already tried standard sorting solutions already on stackoveflow, including concating and merging and flattening. No proper solution has worked for me. 
Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested data structures, especially with the information spread between keys and values, are pain to work with. I'd suggest you convert your object into a flat list of plain objects (put the keys into these objects if needed) and use this list as a base for further processing, like aggregation.

This is how this conversion can be done:

```js
var arr = [
    {
        "Brand 1": [
            {
                "NAME": "SHIRT",
                "SIZE": "M"
            },
            {
                "NAME": "PANTS",
                "SIZE": "L"
            }
        ],
        "Brand 2": [
            {
                "NAME": "JEANS",
                "SIZE": "S"
            },
            {
                "NAME": "TROUSER",
                "SIZE": "S"
            },
            {
                "NAME": "TROUSERS",
                "SIZE": "L"
            }
        ],
        "Brand 3": [
            {
                "SIZE": "L",
                "NAME": "JEANS"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Brand x": [
            {
                "NAME": "SNEAKERS",
                "SIZE": "M"
            }
        ],
        "Brand 2": [
            {
                "NAME": "BLAZER",
                "SIZE": "L"
            },
            {
                "NAME": "FUR COAT",
                "SIZE": "L"
            }
        ],
        "Brand 1": [
            {
                "SIZE": "XL",

                "NAME": "BLAZER"
            }
        ]
    }
];

// build a flat list of objects

let isScalar = x => typeof x !== 'object' || x === null;
let isPlain = x => isScalar(x) || Object.values(x).every(isScalar);

function *flat(obj) {
    if (isPlain(obj))
        yield obj;

    else if (Array.isArray(obj))
        for (let x of obj)
            yield *flat(x);

    else
        for (let key of Object.keys(obj))
            for (let val of flat(obj[key]))
                yield Object.assign(val, {key});
}


let all = [...flat(arr)];

// aggregation examples

let count = function(values) {
    let m = new Map();
    for (let x of values)
        m.set(x, (m.get(x) || 0) + 1);
    return [...m.entries()];
}

let byBrand = count(all.map(x => x.key));
console.log(byBrand);

let bySize = count(all.map(x => x.SIZE));
console.log(bySize);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, However, it displays an error in console: " Cannot convert undefined or null to object"
Though I already did an aggregator function, yours might be different. But that aggregator just flattened the entire array without leaving any trace of keys and structure.. Just plain like a string.

Comment: Why downvote my question fella's? Try it yourself, it isn't like other questions on those lines. this is complex. I have tried almost every solution, nothing works.

Comment: @Zafar: I've tested with what you posted and it worked fine. Is your actual data different?

Comment: thanks. It worked and kind of flattened the array, but I am still clueless how do I aggregate all of the nested arrays into one and count occurrences? Your code give me this:
`[  
   {  
      "sku":"1234",
      "name":"Brand1",
      "key":"Brand1"
   },
   {  
      "sku":"12345",
      "name":"Brand1",
      "key":"Brand1"
   },
   {  
      "sku":"123456",
      "name":"Brand1",
      "key":"Brand1"
   },
   {  
      "sku":"008",
      "name":"Brand2",
      "key":"Brand2"
   }]....]`
isn't it the same as before?

Comment: Create an empty object `counter={}`, iterate the array and for each item, do `counter[item.name] = (counter[item.name] || 0) + 1`. This gives you per-brand counts.

Comment: tried this, but it still gives me several sub-arrays seperated. The counter just says: count: 1 outside each sub array, which means its not taking into account sub-arrays or data sets inside the nested arrays, it is just iterating over the main arrays

Comment: @Zafar: added a complete example

Comment: I need some time to understand this answer. the problem is: my data sets are dynamic, just now I pulled a JSON array from API, it added another subset of arrays, and now this solution doesn't work. Though the answer you posted now works perfectly with above data set.
for example, now it adds another nested array inside "brand", called pictures. So the structure becomes like this: `[{  
      "Brand 1":[  {"PICTURE: {"THUMB":{"URL":"...examples.com"}}, {"PICTURE":{"URL":"examples.com"}}},
            "NAME":"SHIRT",
            "SIZE":"M",
"SKU": 456654
         }]`
it returns an error

Comment: Try replacing this line `if (isPlain(obj))` with something like `if(obj.NAME)` so that it knows when to stop the recursion

Comment: Hi @georg, I have marked this as an answer, after some manipulation with my data. This works! and wow! thank you a lot. I think I will have to get into ES6 now, its a pretty smart thing.